# Not able to find route custom data in angular 6 in app component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an angular application and added custom data to the route given as

```
{ path: 'profile', component: ProfileComponent, data: {title: 'example'} }
```

and in app.component.ts file I have the following code as

```
private route: ActivatedRoute

console.log('route snapshot', this.route.firstChild.data._value.pageType );
```

the error i am getting is

```
ERROR in src/app/app.component.ts(71,64): error TS2339: Property '_value' does not exist on type 'Observable<Data>'.
```

can anyone tell me how to access data of route in app.component.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

You will need to subscribe to the router events in the AppComponent and get the params from it:

```
constructor(private router: Router, route: ActivatedRoute) { }

ngOnInit() {
  this.router.events.subscribe(event => {
    if(event instanceof NavigationEnd){
      console.log(this.route.root.firstChild.snapshot.data['title']);
    }
  });
}
```

If you want it only for that path, you can add one more condition

```
if(event instanceof NavigationEnd && event.url === '/profile')
```

---

**Old Answer**

You will need to access the snapshot to get the data params

```
this.route.snapshot.data['title'];
```

Comment: it is giving undefined

Comment: It should be in the ProfileComponent, not in the AppComponent

Comment: but i want to acces it in app component